# Building a local cube

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, olap, cube

I need to build a local .cub file for my Excel-using clients.

I have scrounged together some VB code but it fails :

```
ConnLocation = "LOCATION=C:\test.cub;"
ConnDSN = "SOURCE_DSN=DSN=TEST;UID=test;PWD=pass;"
ConnCreateCube = _
"CREATECUBE=CREATE CUBE [TestCube] (" & _
"DIMENSION [account_code]);"
Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Provider = "msolap"
Connection.ConnectionString = _
    ConnLocation & _
   ConnDSN & _
ConnCreateCube
```

I have trimmed this down to the above code and am getting a mysterious `OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error.`" when I try to run it.

Any help on the above or suggestions on a different way to approach this would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string DSN property seems wrong:

```
ConnDSN = "SOURCE_DSN=""DSN=TEST;UID=test;PWD=pass;"""
```

Note the quotes.

I would recommend a small code change to make it more intuitive and fail-safe:

```
ConnLoc = "C:\test.cub"
ConnDSN = "DSN=TEST;UID=test;PWD=pass"
ConnSQL = "CREATE CUBE [TestCube] (DIMENSION [account_code])"

Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connection.Provider = "msolap"
Connection.ConnectionString = "LOCATION=""" & ConnLoc & """;" & _
                              "SOURCE_DSN=""" & ConnDSN & """;" & _
                              "CREATECUBE=""" & ConnSQL & """;"
```

Comment: I still get the weird "OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error." - the DSN is functioning and usable from other tools. Not really sure what error might be. 

Thanks for the neater syntax it does make it more readable.

Comment: Hm... Does it say nothing else? When looking for it in Google, these errors often seem to come with a description appended. Is it an exception? Maybe the stack trace tells you more?

Comment: The error is truly obscure and does not give much away about what is happening - e.g. errorcode is -2147467259 ? Do you have any references that might help me ?

Comment: -2147467259 is 0x80004005, which sounds a bit like "Access Denied" to me.