# Portable OLAP Database similar to SQLite or SQL CE

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-server-ce, olap, oltp

I am developing an application with C# and trying to choose the right database platform. My application is a some sort of data analysis tool. I will always make SELECT queries after the initial import of data into the database. I am planning to use SQLite because of the better read performance compared to SQL CE. (I have seen comparisons somewhere)

However, I feel like I need an OLAP database instead of an OLTP database for this purpose. I also read somewhere that SQLite supports only OLTP. Do you know any other PORTABLE library which supports OLAP similar to SQLite? Or what do you recommend for me?

Comment: is this of any use to you: http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/06/complete-olap-infrastructure-without_27.html maybe excel is no good for you but some of the steps he takes may be of use.. maybe there are other ways of interacting with a .cub file? there is more info on the MSDN about AMO:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345091.aspx.. if you get a solution post an answer - i would certainly be interested ;-)

Comment: Do you need a free OLAP server ? what is the sizing of your data ? and the mode of distribution of your application ?

Comment: @gordatron, Thanks, I am looking into thoose and will let you know about how I am going to proceed if I find a way.

Comment: @MarcPolizzi I actually need it to be portable without requiring a installation. I prefer free of course, but paid libraries maybe also be an option. Size is not known in advance, users will know the size. Thanks. I am open for suggestions let me know if you have any recommendation even if it is not an exact fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closer I see is MS [local cubes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801377/building-a-local-cube) that could be accessed in C#. But I guess to create a local cube you would need first a cube in AS and therefore have the multi-dimensional model in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[DuckDB](https://duckdb.org/) project should do exactly what you expect. It is an in-process SQL OLAP database management system. Basically OLAP version of SQLite.

I don't have practical experience with it yet, but it looks very promising.